# Webpack: exclude source-maps from assets list

Tags: webpack, assets, source-maps

I tried excluding source maps in the assets list with no luck

Here's what I tried

```
devtool: 'source-map',
stats: {
  excludeAssets: /\.map$/
}
```

But it's still showing the source maps

```
Version: webpack 2.7.0
       Asset     Size    Chunks             Chunk Names
file1.js.map     117 kB       3  [emitted]  common
   file1.css     110 kB       1  [emitted]  main_css
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't include devtool: 'source-map' if you don't want sourcemaps. 
If you want to conditionally add sourcemaps you can do something like

```
{ devtool : ENABLE_SOURCEMAPS ? 'source-map' : 'none'}
```

Where ENABLE_SOURCEMAP is a variable you define in your file that can be true or false.

Comment: It wasn't supported on 2.7.1, I just has to upgrade my webpack version
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/5377#issuecomment-345789493